# Trying to create a string value from a checkbox that also has a user input

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

I'm new to this if you can't tell by the absurdity of this post, but I'm trying to make something that will take the results of a checkbox and match each option with a numerical value that the user types in. So this is what my interface looks like.

[My GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf22t.png)

I want to be able to make an Order variable from the Order using PHP and make it look something like this when the variable is printed.

2 Filler Choice E, 1 Filler Choice F

Any help would be great and I'm also open to suggestions of how I could do this better because I'm sure this method looks abysmal.

This is my code

```
<div class="container">
                <b><p>Would you like to pre-order any food?</p></b>
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="Order[]" value="Filler Choice E - $100" /> Filler Choice E - $100/Quantity: <input type="number" name= "Quantity5" min="1" max="10"/></p>
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="Order[]" value="Filler Choice F - $100" /> Filler Choice F - $100/Quantity: <input type="number" name= "Quantity6" min="1" max="10"/></p>
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="Order[]" value="Filler Choice G - $100" /> Filler Choice G - $100/Quantity: <input type="number" name= "Quantity7" min="1" max="10"/></p>
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="Order[]" value="Filler Choice H - $100" /> Filler Choice H - $100/Quantity: <input type="number" name= "Quantity8" min="1" max="10"/></p>
        </div>
```

And this is what I have of the PHP code right now. But I dont know how to incorporate the quantities.

```
if(empty($_POST["Order"])){
$Order= "No Order Selected";}
else{
$ArrayOrder = ($_POST['Order']);
$Order = implode(",",$ArrayOrder);}
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP code here.

Comment: @miken32 Sorry, I updated it

Comment: You don't really need these checkboxes. All you need are the quantity number inputs - if one is empty, nothing was ordered for that menu item.

Comment: @El_Vanja I didn’t even think of that, but it’s a good idea! Would you mind posting an example of what that would look like coded?

Comment: It's rather simple, you just check if they're empty (just like you're checking `$_POST["Order"]` now).

Comment: @El_Vanja Sorry, but I’m not sure I’m following. I can see if the values are empty and post the order if there is a value filled in, but wouldn’t that just show the order and not the number of items ordered?

Comment: I'm not saying check the order (we're talking about dropping the whole thing, so what sense would that make?), I'm saying use the same logic, but directly on quantities (`if(!empty($_POST['Quantity5'])) { // this was ordered`).

Comment: @El_Vanja hey I forgot to thank you, I did your suggestion and everything worked out. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)